# Creating a dataframe with a range of datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm creating a dataframe that has a range of dates in datetime. This works but I know there must be a more elegant way to do this. Any thoughts?

```
date_range = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(date(2019,8,30), date.today(), freq='D'))
date_range.rename(columns = {0:'date'}, inplace=True)
date_range = pd.DataFrame(set(date_range['date'].dt.date))
date_range.rename(columns = {0:'date'}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the rename parts you can name them directly

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
date_range = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(date(2019,8,30), date.today(), freq='D')})
date_range = pd.DataFrame({'date':set(date_range['date'].dt.date)})
```